# How to add multiple of the same node to a view?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to write a piece of code that, using a timer, 'drops' a ball from the top of the view from one of three positions, every second. When the first ball is released, it works, however, after the timer causes the function to be called again, the code crashes because it says the node cannot be added again to the view.

Can someone explain to me a way to make this work?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    //Creates the three circles
    let circleOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    let circleTwo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    let circleThree = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")

    //Creates dropping ball
    let droppingBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")

    //Creates variables to play game
    var gameStarted = false
    var gameOver = false
    var timeInterval = 1.0
    var droppingBallXPosition = 0
    var livesLeft = 3


    //Creates timer for the balls
    var ballTimer = NSTimer()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //Set background colour
        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //Assigns position to circles
        circleOne.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        circleTwo.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height / 2)
        circleThree.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height / 2)

        //Assigns size to circles
        circleOne.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        circleTwo.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
        circleThree.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)

        //Set colour to circles
        circleOne.color = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        circleOne.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        circleTwo.color = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        circleTwo.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        circleThree.color = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        circleThree.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

        //Add circles to view
        self.addChild(circleOne)
        self.addChild(circleTwo)
        self.addChild(circleThree)

        //set properties for falling ball
        droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(droppingBallXPosition), y: 0)
        droppingBall.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
        droppingBall.color = UIColor.redColor()
        droppingBall.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        droppingBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


        }
    func releaseBall(){
        var whichColumn = arc4random() % 3

        switch whichColumn {
        case 0:
            droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height)
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
            self.addChild(droppingBall)
            break
        case 1:
            droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height)
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
            self.addChild(droppingBall)

            break
        case 2:
            droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height)
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
            self.addChild(droppingBall)

            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        if gameStarted == false {
            let zoomOut = SKAction.scaleTo(0.1, duration: 0.2)
            circleTwo.runAction(zoomOut)
            gameStarted = true
        }
        else if gameStarted == true && gameOver == false {
            //check to see if the game is over
            if livesLeft > 0 {
                //Continue game
                ballTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.releaseBall), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            }
            else {
                //The player has lost
                gameOver = true
                gameStarted = false
            }
        }
        else if gameStarted == true && gameOver == true {
            //The player has lost
            gameOver = true
            gameStarted = false
        }

    }



    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

The error:

> Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent

Answer (score 0):

You can create a duplicate ball to add to the scene every time you add another ball. This would be an alternate solution rather than a proper answer though, because doing this properly would involve creating a class for the balls. This way, all you need to do is create a new sprite in each switch case like this:

```
let ballCopy = droppingBall.copy() as! SKSpritenode
```

Then, you'd only change its position (because using `copy` copies everything about the node being copied) to wherever the the switch case says to go. All in all, it should look something like this:

```
func releaseBall(){

        var whichColumn = arc4random() % 3

        droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0

        switch whichColumn {

          case 0:

            let ballCopy1 = droppingBall.copy() as! SKSpritenode

            ballCopy1.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height)
            self.addChild(ballCopy1)

            break

          case 1:

            let ballCopy2 = droppingBall.copy() as! SKSpritenode

            ballCopy2.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height)
            self.addChild(ballCopy2)

            break

          case 2:

            let ballCopy3 = droppingBall.copy() as! SKSpritenode

            ballCopy3.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height)

            self.addChild(ballCopy3)

            break

          default:
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've tried to move the repeated code 'droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction' to the start of the function before the switch, and I've also moved the 'self.addChild(droppingBall)' to the end of the switch. However neither of these seemed to make a difference as I still get the exact same error.

Comment: You can use `copy` to create a duplicate of the node then set a new position for the new ball. I'll change my answer to that

Answer (score 0):

Is only one ball on the screen at once? If so you could change your func :

```
func releaseBall(){
self.droppingball.removefromparent()

    var whichColumn = arc4random() % 3
    switch whichColumn {
    case 0:
        droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height)
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
        self.addChild(droppingBall)
        break
    case 1:
        droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height)
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
        self.addChild(droppingBall)

        break
    case 2:
        droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height)
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
        self.addChild(droppingBall)

        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This should allow you to run the function multiple times.
If the system requires multiple balls. You could create a second sprite node and a second func to release balls and set the timers to start at different dates.

Like this:

```
    var droppingball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
         var droppingball0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
func releaseBall(){
self.droppingball.removefromparent()
var whichColumn = arc4random() % 3
switch whichColumn {
case 0:
    droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall)
    break
case 1:
    droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall)

    break
case 2:
    droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall)

    break
default:
    break
}
}
func releaseBall0(){
self.droppingball.removefromparent()

var whichColumn = arc4random() % 3
switch whichColumn {
case 0:
    droppingBall.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall)
    break
case 1:
    droppingBall0.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2), y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall0)

    break
case 2:
    droppingBall0.position = CGPoint(x: (self.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: self.frame.height)
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    droppingBall0.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0
    self.addChild(droppingBall0)

    break
default:
    break
}
```

}
Then all you would need to do is figure out the interval that you wanted to call this function and add two timers double that interval. For example if I wanted to fire every second you would create two timers with scheduled time intervals of 2 seconds and tell one to start 1 second after the first by pocketing it in:

```
        dispatch_after(
                dispatch_time(
                    DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                    Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
                ),
                dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                {
// your timer
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because the Node has already been added to the scene, you can only add it once. You'll need to create a new instance of SKSpriteNode and then add it to the scene each time you want another ball. You might want to create a custom class for your balls and store them in a list, so you can identify each one if you need to.